# How do I override the document viewer icon to view in Full Screen in Plone?

Tags: python, linux, plone

Where exactly can I override the collective.documentviewer code to disable the icon to view the document full screen in another window? Actually when I only click on the 'customize'  button for the documentviewer in zcml it throws up an exception for 'widget', even without addition of a letter of code there and the viewer crashes.I am using version 2.2.1 for collective.documentviewer and Plone 4.1.4 on linux. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to carefully blank the `<div>`  section for 'View Document in Fullscreen'  in this javascript: 
collective.documentviewer-2.2.1 py2.6.egg/collective/documentviewer/resources/assets/viewer.js